# Is there a faster way to search for a calendar event using AppleScript by UID?

Tags: applescript

I'm doing a lookup for a calendar event in AppleScript by UID using the following code:

```
set myEvents to ((events of myCal) whose uid = myUID)
```

This works, however, depending on the size of the Calendar, it can be rather slow, as it iterates through all of the events until it finds the matching events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a script library [CalendarLib](http://macosxautomation.com/applescript/apps/Script_Libs.html#CalendarLib) on macosxautomation.com based on Cocoa.

It's much faster than the traditional AppleScript dictionary of Calendar.app

Comment: Thanks! That looks to be exactly what I am looking for!